# IPhone core data simulator

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios-simulator

I've created an app that uses core data. Is there a way to view the sqlite db on the simulator? A tool perhaps that allows to query the sqlite db on the simulator? Like a data browser?

Is there a way to browse the iphone simulator to the sqlite db location?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Xcode 5

I just downloaded a trial of [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/) and was able to point it at the .sql database from the simulator via:

/Macintosh HD/Users/"username"/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/"current iOS development version"/Applications/

The folder names for the applications are unreadable, but if you click on the folder you should be able to see the contents with familiar names.

## Xcode 6+

This was changed in Xcode 6, and now is located at `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<device-id>/data/Containers/Data/Appl‌​action` where the database itself can be found within the documents directory `<app-id>/Documents/<name>.sqlite`

Comment: This is not correct as of XCode 6+. Look in 
`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<device-id>/data/Containers/Data/Application`

Comment: Anybody know how to get <device-id> inside xCode?

Answer (score 14):

With Xcode 6, the simulator base directory can be found here:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<device-id>/data/Containers/Data/Application
```

Then, the database itself can be found in the documents directory:

```
<app-id>/Documents/<name>.sqlite
```

The database can be accessed using `sqlite3` on the command line.

Comment: The currently accepted answer is no longer correct.  Please spare your up-votes to get this one to the top!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Lita](http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58), free and quite good.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the free `sqlite3` installed, you can do so at the command line by doing:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/<sim_version>/Applications/<apphash>/Documents/<yourfile>
```

Easiest way to see which hash you should peek in:

```
ls -lt /Users/<user>/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/<sim_version>/Applications/
```

You can run `.tables` at the prompt to see what tables are there, and `.schema <tablename>` to check out its columns.

Answer (score 0):

i´m quite happy with [SQLite Manger](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) for Firefox. Free AddOn.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite an old post, however I was looking for something else and I landed here, my 2 cents:

In reply to WINSergey:
(1) The easiest way to recover your device ID and the entire path is to print:

```
  NSLog(@"app dir: %@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                     URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                     inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
```

Then you'll see the output on the Debugging area or opening the System Log from the simulator.

(2) Also, to know the Device ID from the simulator: XCode > WIndow > Devices >  > it shows the Identifier on the right hand side.

I'm also using SQLiteStudio, it is Open Source and works well.