# Visible SQLite file but invisible data in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios-simulator

i've created an app that uses Core-data. Now i want to see the data that i've stored in various entities in that app. App has been installed in iOS-simulator (7.0.3)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023954/iphone-core-data-simulator) did not help

ScreenShot:[image: Table schema]

[image: Here is the Empty table]

And here is how I am saving the data..

```
EffController *newController = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EffController" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    newController.name=@"fgfghjfghj";
    newController.uniqueUID= @"ffghfg";
    newController.parentOutputID = @0;
    newController.localIP=@"***.***.***.***";
    newController.localPort= @XXXX;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]
                                    initWithEntityName:@"EffControllerType"];
    NSError *requestError = nil;
    /* And execute the fetch request on the context */
    NSArray *types = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&requestError];

    for (EffControllerType *type in types) {
        if ([type.name isEqualToString:@"***********"]) {
            newController.type= type;
            break;
        }
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![newController.managedObjectContext save:&error]) { //here is the mistake.
    //It should be self.managedobjectContext    
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
```

**Edit**  
 After long discussion with @HaniIbrahim problem was solved… But still not clear about **why the content was visible in app, not in sqlite file? & why context for managed object?** Can anybody help to find real issue behind the topic?

Comment: Is the problem is that you save things in your application life cycle  while you can't find it in the SQLite file? And also you can't find it in the next run?

Comment: Yes.. I can find SQLite file, but not the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you insert, update or delete anything in CoreData you have to save context to actual apply your updates

```
NSError *error = nil;
[context save:&error]; // context is your managedObjectContext that you use to communicate with coreData
```

---

**Edit**

After you post your code I found that you are using two context `self.managedObjectContext` and `newController.managedObjectContext` ?

Comment: yeah. i know that. I've done that. I am able to see data in my application. What i am unable to see is data in .sqlite file.

Comment: and you see the updates you have made if you close the app and run it again?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the sqlite file? especially the table that is supposed to have the data you inserted?

Comment: Posted the screenshot

Comment: Sorry; I meant the data not the scheme. I just want to be sure that the table is empty ... It's really weird !

Comment: OK :D ... Are you sure that `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` uses this file ... you can log the path of its SQLite file and check if it uses the same file ... you can also check if there are more than one SQLite file

Comment: After you post the code I feel there is a big problem here ... You are not calling the same context here `self.managedObjectContext` or  `newController.managedObjectContext` ? .... I checked the reference and found that the managedObject and have pointer to its context.

Comment: Oops… But still .. No data

Comment: Hey it worked… I had to reset data of simulator & then had to delete files from application folder. Please update your answer & let me know so that i can accept it

Comment: Glad it worked, However I checked the documentation and found that the managedObject can has its context.

Comment: still i am not clear about the issue.. why the content was visible in app, not in sqlite file? & why context for managed object? shall i update my question & mark your answer as helpful but not accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the data by using `SQLite Manager` plugin for Firefox. Open firefox -> Install the plugin -> Open the plugin -> navigate to the below path using Open File option

```
Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/VERSION_OF_YOUR_SIMULATOR/Applications/YOUR_PROJECT(Usually in alphanumeric)/YOUR_DB_FILE.sqlite
```

That should do.

There are number of plugins and applications available similar to SQLite Manager. You may choose that as per your desire.

Comment: I do have SQLite Manager.. Unable to find the file in given path.

Comment: Open a folder.. Press Cmd + Shift + G and then enter ~Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ ... You should be able to navigate through

Comment: Ya i know that, I am able to access the folder. there is no .sqlite file there. Although there is a sqlite file in ~yourPath/document/, but the issue is it is not containing new data. It just has imported data from start. Even if i delete it, it comes back on next boot. Really strange.

Comment: Hmmm.. Did you make sure you open the correct project folder? Because you might have lots of project folders inside with alphanumeric names. It may confuse.. That's why

Comment: yeah i am sure about that. I don't have any other project using Core-data.. i reset my simulator contents